# What are the correct dimensions for the App Icons in Images.xcassets

Tags: ios, xcode, icons

My AppIcon group in Images.xcassets has 4 boxes where you can place icons for different devices and iOS versions. However, I have tried several different icon dimensions I have found online, and each of them produces some form of error when I try to build, archive, or validate the project.

What are the correct app icon dimensions for the AppIcon set?

Comment: Xcode shows you the needed size. Show the Utility pane on the right side of Xcode. Select one of the app icon boxes. In the Utility pane, click the tab with down arrow icon. Now you see details about the icon.

Comment: @rmaddy Can you clarify what you mean by "select one of the icon boxes"? Not seeing to what you are referring.

Comment: @Praxiteles See the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

To view the sizes, select the blank image space that you are interested in and click the size inspector. The size shows up at the bottom RHS along with the iOS version that it is targeted to.

Your screen should look something like this.

[image: App icon example]

iPhone 6 requires two new images.

```
180x180
Icon-iPhone-60@3x.png


87x87
Icon-Small@3x.png
```

If you look at the JSON for the appiconset it should look something like this. The first line has the sizes. Note that some icons are used in multiple places. The names are arbitrary but I kept the same naming convention as before.

```
{
  "images" : [
    {
      "size" : "29x29",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "Icon-Small.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "29x29",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "Icon-Small@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "29x29",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "Icon-Small@3x.png",
      "scale" : "3x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "40x40",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "Icon-40@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "40x40",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "Icon-iPhone-60@2x.png",
      "scale" : "3x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "57x57",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "Icon.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "57x57",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "Icon@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "60x60",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "Icon-iPhone-60@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "60x60",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "Icon-iPhone-60@3x.png",
      "scale" : "3x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "29x29",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "Icon-Small.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "29x29",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "Icon-Small@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "40x40",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "Icon-40.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "40x40",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "Icon-40@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "50x50",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "Icon-Small-50.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "50x50",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "Icon-Small-50@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "72x72",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "Icon-72.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "72x72",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "Icon-72@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "76x76",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "Icon-iPad-76.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "76x76",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "Icon-iPad-76@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    }
  ],
  "info" : {
    "version" : 1,
    "author" : "xcode"
  },
  "properties" : {
    "pre-rendered" : true
  }
}
```