# iOS 9 Launch Image sizes?

Tags: ios, xcasset, launchimage

I'm confused about Launch Images. I have to fill out the Launch Images in the `xcassets` file and I see this:

[image]

But I can't find any documentation which lists the sizes needed for any of these images. [Apples documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1) only specifies 5 different sizes while this grid is asking for 8. Also, it only defines sizes by the model of the phone, while this grid uses iOS versions and Retina display sizes.

Where can I find the sizing specifications for the 8 items in this grid?

Comment: I think that these days you are better off using a storyboard. I think that's the preferred method now.

Comment: I don't use storyboards. Can't stand it when a checkbox buried in some constantly changing UI is overriding my code. Makes it a nightmere to collaborate and maintain a project

Comment: If you select them it will say the expected size at the bottom of the attributes inspector

Comment: @dan thank you! found it. Example B of why I don't like using xcode's UI builders lol

Comment: If you do not use storyboards for the main interface of your app, you can still choose to use a storyboard just for launch images.

Comment: oh yea I have one for iPhone 6 as specified in the docs, but iPhone 5 needs the xcassets http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21668497/uiscreen-mainscreen-bounds-returning-wrong-size

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incorrect launch image size](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30445425/2108547)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incorrect launch image size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30445171/incorrect-launch-image-size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found 2 resources for finding the image size

1. [apple documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/AddingImages.html)
2. [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26127056/6347547)

it knows which resource to use based on your phone.

Retina HD 5.5 = iPhone 6+ (which only had iOS 8 or 9)

Retina HD 4.7 = iPhone 6 (which only had iOS 8 or 9)

Retina HD 4 = iPhone 5 (which only had iOS 7 - 9)

Comment: The first link doesn't answer anything about size specs. The second one would've helped me but I didn't think to expand my search beyond Launch Images. Good to link up answers to similar questions. Thanks for the additional info

Comment: the launch screen image is any size, the uiView is a pretty generic uiVIew that can support anything it just needs your size class restraints

Comment: doesn't support iPhone 5 though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21668497/uiscreen-mainscreen-bounds-returning-wrong-size